# How to use CMAKE for C++11 on windows?

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, cmake, mingw, clang

My C++11 project is currently using CMAKE, XCODE, CLANG on OSX. I wish to compile this code on Windows.

Plan is to use the same cmake settings files on windows. Best case would be to use CMAKE to generate VS projects which uses Clang or gcc for C++11 .

Seems to me, that Visual Studio is just not going to fully support C++11 for a while. So we should all try to find a general solution for cross platform C++11.

How would one use CMAKE to generate projects/makefiles which would compile C++11 code on windows?

Comment: `use CMAKE to generate VS projects which uses Clang` it's not related to cmake, you need to check llvm status. afaik it's quite [experimental](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html): `... clang cannot parse the C++ standard library included with Visual Studio ...`

Comment: Ninja files or MSYS Makefiles are fine too. clang has its own std=c++11 .

Comment: gcc on windows is relatively easy with MinGW. But why not use VS? VS2013 supports most c++11 features and even VS2010 supports some features, e.g lamda, auto, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake's Visual Studio generator will always use the `cl` compiler of Visual C++.

What you request would require writing a new Generator for CMake. That is, the problem cannot be solved by writing a clever `CMakeLists.txt`, but has to be solved by adding a feature to the CMake core binary itself. I agree that this could be useful once Clang achieves a suitable level of Windows support, but at the point of this writing, it is probably too early for that.

You might want to take a look at the [experimental `compile-features` mechanism](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html) for CMake. This is not yet part of CMake 3.0, but is planned to be integrated with one of the next releases. The idea is that you just specify which C++11 features you need and CMake takes care of configuring the compiler accordingly (or gives an error if the compiler does not support the feature at all).

Comment: That is in master by now: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create VS projects which use clang by specifying the LLVM toolset when you generate.

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14863

Eg:

```
cmake.exe .. -T LLVM-vs2010
```

Comment: The solution to get C++11 on Windows is to bypass the Visual Studio Compiler. Seems reasonable.